# Selenium RC Jmeter C# LoadTesting

Tags: c#, selenium-rc, jmeter, load-testing

I am using a winforms application to do functional testing of java web applications hosted on a server. The whole application uses data driven testing, where i input the tests to be performed from an Excel and the application reads it and executes the test cases on the browser using selenium RC. While the steps mentioned in the excel are executed i generate a report in parallel confirming about the presence/state etc. of elements.

I would want to integrate jMeter here, using c# to compute the performance parameters e.g. use the command line functionality of Jmeter and pass the URL to jMeter.

I can use jMeter standalone, but i want to give the testing team an option to use it as a one stop tool for all testing and use the same test cases as the functional tests. Are there any libraries available that can compute the web response times for any operation and generate graphs/analytics for concurrent users as well.

Thanks in Advance

-ABY

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to research the same question. The answer I came up with from a literature review was no. As for C#, Jmeter is integrated with jUnit. I do not see any mention of Nunit or MSTest support in the Apache docs. Microsoft provides a JDBC driver for SQL Server that would allow you to test execution times for queries. If you did find this supported, note that a best practice is to use HTMLUnitDriver for headless execution (no thousands of browser instances popping up).

Also most commentary has stated that although functional Selenium tests can be integrated into JMeter, Jmeter reports actions on the protocol level and instrumented Selenium code operates at the DOM object level. You lose the granularity required to support metrics around the various events during page load (randomly I am thinking of comparing the overall time for a page to load against the difference between redirectStart and redirectEnd) or client side activities like input from a form validation.

Comment: well, one approach could be to use rigid scripts for testing using jmeter command line and dump the results into some database using the jmeter post processing functionality. And later use C# to query the results and show it in its own graphs. A bit tedious task but achievable.